# Se envía doble correo el primero con datos vacíos

Tags: php, reactjs, phpmailer, axios, react-hooks

Estoy teniendo un problema, mi proyecto es con **REACT JS**, con **axios** mandando un objeto con los datos de un formulario ejecuto un archivo **php** que hace el envío de correo con **PHP Mailer**, pero no sé porque razón siempre se envía primero un correo con los datos en vacío y llega uno segundo con todos los datos.

Así esta mi codigo:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <div className="form-row">
          <label>Nombre:</label> 
          <input type="text" name="nombre" value={nombre} onChange={onChangeName} required/>
     </div>
     <div className="form-row">
          <label>Email:</label> 
          <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={onChangeEmail} required/>
     </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Unirse"/>
 </form>
```

y el submit:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const obj = {
        nombre: nombre,
        email: email
    }
    axios.post('https://dominio/archivo.php', obj)
            .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    if(response.data.success){
                                swal("Enviado", "El correo a sido enviado correctamente", "success");
                                colocarNombre("");
                                colocarEmail("");
                            }else{
                                if(response.data.error){
                                    swal("Error", "Ocurrio un problema al enviar el correo", "error");
                                }
                    }
            })
}
```

y mi archivo php:

```
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail->Host = 'mail.dominio';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'correo';
$mail->Password = 'pssw';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
 'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('correo', 'dest');
$mail->addAddress('correo2', 'dest');
$mail->Subject = 'Formulario ';
$body = ' <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> </head> 
<body> <h3>¡Suscripción !</h3> 
<p> <strong> Nombre: </strong> '. $nombre .'</p>
<p> <strong> Email: </strong> '. $email .'</p></body> </html>';
 $mail->Body = $body;
 if (!$mail->send()) {
    $response['error']['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error en el envío del correo.';
    } else {
     $response['success']['message'] = 'Nos comunicaremos contigo lo antes posible.';
    }
```

Utilice Postman para ver si era algun problema del backend pero si hago el post desde ahí si funciona, solo se envía uno y con los datos. Estoy algo bloqueada si saben algo sería de mucha ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es algo normal, la request que estás haciendo mediante JS se considera una *Preflighted Request*, en otras palabras, el navegador envía primero una request de tipo **OPTIONS** y después ya envía la respuesta de tipo **POST** con el objeto.

La solución es muy simple, y es algo que deberías haber hecho desde el principio, que es verificar que los datos que quieres mandar en tu mail existen y no son nulos o vacíos.

```
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (isset($nombre) && isset($email)) {
    $mail->Host = 'mail.dominio';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'correo';
    $mail->Password = 'pssw';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->setFrom('correo', 'dest');
    $mail->addAddress('correo2', 'dest');
    $mail->Subject = 'Formulario ';
    $body = ' <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> </head> 
    <body> <h3>¡Suscripción !</h3> 
    <p> <strong> Nombre: </strong> '. $nombre .'</p>
    <p> <strong> Email: </strong> '. $email .'</p></body> </html>';
    $mail->Body = $body;
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $response['error']['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error en el envío del correo.';
        } else {
        $response['success']['message'] = 'Nos comunicaremos contigo lo antes posible.';
        }
}
```

Esta pequeña modificación que acabo de hacer a tu código PHP debería arreglar el problema de que se te estén enviando dos mails, uno de los cuales no tiene ningún dato. No obstante, te recomendaría que estudies PHP más en profundidad, pues este código tiene varios problemas.

Uno de los cuales, es que estás confiando ciegamente en el input del usuario (nombre y email), y esto es algo que no debes hacer jamás, porque un supuesto hacker podría introducir datos que no esperas en ese formulario (JavaScript, etc...), como mínimo, siempre que utilices input del usuario final debes de sanear esos datos (escapar caracteres HTML como mínimo).

Comment: También  se tiene que poner alguna medida de seguridad al recibir el post. Si no se pone nada se puede llamar a esa funcion tantas veces que deje la aplicación sin uso de mail, por lo que el aplicativo quedaría inservible hasta la renovación de estado

Comment: @ICIM Si, en efecto ya dije que ese código PHP tiene muchos problemas. Aparte como tu correctamente mencionas es una puerta abierta a un ataque DDOS y hacer que te reporten tu mail por SPAM.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que faltaba muchas gracias por tus comentarios voy a agregarle más validaciones. n.n